# upgrading Cloudera hadoop from cdh3u6 to cdh5

Tags: hadoop, migration, upgrade, cloudera

In my project, we are looking for upgrading Hadoop and hive from cdh3 to a higher version.
We planned to upgrade from cdh3 to chd4 first,but recent enhancements states that, cdh5 is more stable version.
So we have planned to upgrade to cdh5.
But I'm looking for a documentation where i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to go from 3 to 4 and then from 4 to 5.  I don't know what components you use in 3, but be careful as there is a significant change to HBase between 4 and 5.  Best of luck to you!  Here is the link to the doc:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM5/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Managing-Clusters/cm5mc_upgrade_cdh3_to_4.html